# Gstreamer: increase and decrease delay on-the-fly

Tags: video-streaming, delay, gstreamer

I have a GStreamer pipeline to play live video from RTSP source. I want the user to be able to increase / decrease the delay. My approach to this is to have a `queue` element and manipulate its `min-threshold-time` parameter.

This seems to work at start. On for instance 10 seconds delay, The pipeline starts frozen, and continues after 10 seconds. But if I manipulate the time, nothing happens. I have tried other parameters as well, like `max-size-time`, without luck. `leaky` parameter causes the video to be jerky and bad quality.

Currently I am stopping and re-starting the pipeline, which looks terrible.

Pipeline I am using:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=<...> ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! capsfilter caps=video/x-h264 ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! queue min-threshold-delay=<delay> ! autovideosink
```

Is there a command to force queue to flush the frames, some other element better suitable, or some other trick to accomplish this?

Comment: what about pausing changing parameter and playing? I am not sure if changing elements parameters dynamically is going to work just by setting the parameter - maybe you will have to do some pad blocking etc like you would when you [dynamicaly change the pipeline](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html)

Comment: @otopolsky: Your proposal is an improvement. Pausing and re-playing indeed works when increasing the delay, but when decreasing the delay, nothing happens.

Comment: glad to help a bit, your solution is quite advanced using latency events.. nicely done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working. Here's my solution:

Pipeline:

```
rtspsrc location=<...> ! rtph264depay ! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-time=$MAX_DELAY ! queue max-size-time=$SMALL_DELAY min-threshold-time=$DELAY ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

where:

- $DELAY = video delay in gst time units
- $MAX_DELAY = maximum video delay in gst time units
- $SMALL_DELAY = a minimum delay, for instance like one millisecond, in gst time units

The strategy is to have two queues, where the first one acts as a buffer, and the second acts as a balancer that ensures all messages are delayed exactly $DELAY amount of time. This can not be accomplished using one queue.

Runtime:

When the delay needs to be changed, the $DELAY value is changed on the second queue. After this, the pipeline needs to be sent a **latency event** using the new delay as latency. This causes the pipeline either freeze for a moment (if delay is increased), or to fast forward to catch up (if delay is decreased).

Buffering status can be obtained by reading current-level-time property on the first queue and comparing it to delay that was set.

Comment: Hi, how exactly do you send the latency event to the pipeline? from command line? thx!

Comment: @herrfz The events can not be sent in commandline, as it is for creating a static pipeline and for more dynamic pipeline manipulation you would have to use a programming language to access the gstreamer API.